# Add graphQL fragment to schema, and have available for all queries

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

The following executes correctly in graphiQL

```
fragment BookGridFields on Book {
  _id
  title
}

{
  allBooks {
    ...BookGridFields
  }
}
```

---

My question is, it possible to specify the fragment right in my schema, right below where my Book type is defined, like so

```
type Book {
  _id: String
  title: String
  pages: Int
  weight: Float
  authors: [Author]
}

fragment BookGridFields on Book {
  _id
  title
}
```

So that I could just run queries like this

```
{
  allBooks {
    ...BookGridFields
  }
}
```

without needing to define the fragment as part of my query.

Currently the above errors with

> Unknown fragment \"BookGridFields\"

Comment: I don;t think you define fragments on the server. You define them on the client when performing a query: http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments and http://dev.apollodata.com/react/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I've seen both of those - does seem to be impossible, but I figured I'd check the experts here :)

Comment: You didn't tag the question with apollo but the link I posted allows re usable fragments. I guess it depends on the client library you are using.

Comment: They're re-using fragments, but only by sticking the fragment string on a variable and passing it around.  I mean that'll work, of course, but I am still curious to hear if it's definitively not possible to have the schema itself define a fragment, so app code doesn't have to.

Comment: It's definitely currently not possible as part of vanilla GraphQL. What benefits are you looking to get from sharing fragments from the server?

Comment: @stubailo I'm still new to GraphQL - it  just, intuitively, seemed to make more sense that I'd define it in my schema, with application use cases in mind, so I wouldn't have to maintain and pass around the fragment in application code.  But your tweets make a lot of sense.  If you wanna add that as an answer I'd be happy to upvote and accept, to benefit anyone who might find this question.

Answer (score 18):

Per the graphql docs, I see that fragments are a part of the query api and not valid syntax for setting up a schema. This leads me to conclude that it is not currently possible to specify a fragment in a schema.

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments

Comment: Which makes defining interfaces really, really dumb.

Comment: @BenjaminR OT, maybe, but can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: @jberryman I think BenjaminR means that there is unnecessary redundancy in interface implementations (fields have to be specified in the interface and the implementing type, sort of diminishing the value of using interfaces in the first place.)  I use Dgraph and have noticed they allow schemas that don't repeat interface fields in their implementing types, which is really great.

Comment: the redundancy when writing graphql in general is really really dumb